# Historical stock data with official open/close

Tags: historical-data

Is there a source of historical US stock end-of-day data that contains the official open/close prices from listing exchange (that is, the prices that usually come from the opening/closing auctions)?

The providers I've look at so far (norgate, csidata) use the first and last regular-hours trades from the consolidate tape as their open/close prices.

Edit: I should mention that I'm also looking for a source that has 20-30 years of history and includes delisted stocks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get primary exchange prices from the Interactive Brokers API by specifying the primary exchange when making [historical data requests](http://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/historical_bars.html), although this is not documented, and the IB API can be difficult to use. [QuantRocket](https://www.quantrocket.com/docs/#primary-vs-consolidated-prices) provides a `--primary-exchange` flag to do this for you.

Alternatively (though likely harder and more expensive if you only care about EOD data), Ernie Chan [suggests getting tick data](https://epchan.blogspot.com/2015/04/beware-of-low-frequency-data.html) which may include a "Cross" flag to identify the opening/closing print.

Comment: Thanks. I neglected to mention that I'm looking for a source that includes delisted stocks so IB is out unfortunately.